# How to check which build of WSL2 am I running?

Tags: windows, version, wsl-2

Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 is great tool, but has some issues as it's still a work in progress. I'm not on Insiders Program, so I don't get newest builds. I need to deal with some memory issues which are supposed to be fixed already, but I can't figure out if I already have required build or do I need to do some upgrading or is it available only for Insiders at the moment.

My Windows build is 19042.985 (v.20H2)

On Settings -> Apps there's WSL described with 4.19.104

So which [build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes) am I using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found it by running this command in Powershell:

```
(gcm wsl).Version
```

`gcm` is short for `Get-Command` which gives basic information about command, including full version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19041  488
```

So my build is 19041.

4.19.104, seen on Settings -> Apps, is the version of the [WSL kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/kernel-release-notes).

---

Another way available in Ubuntu (don't know about other distributions) is to run `wslfetch` command which prints basic information including build number:
[image: wslfetch]

Comment: I just tried both ways and they gave different build numbers. And yours differ too: 19401 and 19044. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I just updated to the newest build which supports GUI apps and I'm sure the update worked because I can run GUI apps now, but both build numbers mentioned in your post didn't change.

Comment: @dyedwiper they are different because I added wslfetch option to my answer much later. I've just tried both options and they show the same build number (currently it's 22621)